# Sql Query with NOT LIKE IN WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables *emails* and *blockedSender* I am trying to remove blocked sender from the email query. e.g.

emails table:

| user_id | from_address |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name-1 <email-1@address.com> |
| 2 | name-2 <email-2@address.com> |

blockedSender table:

| blocked_address |
| --- |
| email-1@address.com |

Here I want to return all elements from the emails table where the from_address does not do a LIKE match with entries in the blocked address. Something similar to

```
select email_id, from_address 
from emails e 
where from_address not like in (select '%' + blocked_address + '%' 
                                from blockSenders)
```

which does not work because of incorrect syntax. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can express this using *not exists*

```
select e.email_id, e.from_address
from emails e 
where not exists (
    select * from blockedSenders b 
    where e.from_address like '%' + b.blocked_address + '%'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be rewritten as `JOIN`:

```
select e.email_id, e.from_address 
from emails e
left join blockSenders b
  ON e.from_address LIKE '%' + b.blocked_address + '%' 
where b.blocked_address IS NULL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2ff7d8cc7ca8b4aeb42f018bf255590)**